# PyCharm displays rubbish characters with Inconsolata

Tags: fonts, pycharm

I am using PyCharm Community Edition 4 (on Windows 8.1) Build: #PC-139.1659, and tried to specify Inconsolata as the primary font. This is what I immediately get in the Settings --> Editor --> Colors & Fonts --> Font dialog:

[image]

As can be seen in the second paragraph in the above picture, PyCharm places an apostrophe character (only in lowercase characters) at the position where the letter `m` must be. This causes the letter `m` and all lowercase letters that follow it alphabetically, to be displaced by one position. To put it simple, the result is rubbish.

How do I know that this is a PyCharm problem and not a font problem?

I simply selected the text shown in the dialog and copied + pasted it both in Notepad and in Word. Both these programs display the correct text:

[image]

**My question**:

Is this a known problem and if so, is there any (recommended) workaround?

Comment: I could not reproduce this with my own instance of PyCharm. On Windows Server 2012, PyCharm Professional 4.0.6.

Comment: Since you're on Windows, just use Consolas instead of Inconsolata.

Comment: @HongOoi, This seems to be a too-radical solution, like cutting the heads of the on-lookers if there is a scratch on the face ... :)

Comment: what happens if you turn off source code pro fallback?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, I turned off the fallback in the dialog as per your suggestion. Still the same problem :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try disabling anti-aliasing using the setting "Use anti-aliased font". I have the same problem with a different font and this oddly works for me.

Comment: Steve, thank you so much!  Disabling anti-aliasing using the setting "Use anti-aliased font" solved the problem.

Comment: Another curious thing is that if Windows ClearType is disabled the setting "Use anti-aliased font" can be enabled. That might be a better solution, but also pointing more towards ClearType as the part of the problem.

Comment: Editing the .vmoptions with font options as described [here](http://superuser.com/questions/614960/how-to-fix-font-anti-aliasing-in-intellij-idea-when-using-high-dpi) seems to work best of all.